# Fp Growth Algorithm using CUDA

Tags: cuda, data-mining

i have to develop a data mining algorithm using CUDA. I have searched a lot and found that most algorithms have already been implemented except FpGrowth.
do you think its a good idea? can you give me any ideas on how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

I will answer your first question: "is it a good idea?". Well, I think that it is a good idea if you need it.  But, if you just want to do it because it has not been done, maybe it is not a so good idea.

For the second question, make sure that you understand FPGrowth well. You can read the original paper describing FPGrowth. Also you can check the book "Introduction to data mining". It has an easy-to-understand description of FPGrowth. After you understand well FPGrowth, you can see how to implement it with CUDA... That is my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I found a web page which describe how to draw a FP tree and how to identify the frequent patterns from that tree. you can visit that site and read the information.

[How to identify frequent patterns using FP tree algorithm](http://hareenlaks.blogspot.com/2011/06/fp-tree-example-how-to-identify.html)

Answer (score -2):

I don't know FpGrowth but i guess you have read the papers ( http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.162.1209&rep=rep1&type=pdf , etc.). I guess you are new to CUDA which makes implementing something this complicated rather difficult.

The key to good performance with CUDA is massive uniform parallelism and litte synchronization. The CUDA Zone http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_apps_flash_new.html has a lot of good examples what works and how. A good starting point for learning CUDA is the programming guide http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_2_prod/toolkit/docs/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf .

A frequent question is "I've got this C code, how do i port it to CUDA". The answer is don't! In CUDA there are no pointers, no strings, no printing, no files and most of what you have learned about efficient code is wrong.

A more promising approach is to think of the underlying algorithm in a more abstract way. Identify what can be done in parallel, think about a good datastructure (probably involving large arrays), implement a prototype. It might be easier to rely on CUDA libraries like Thrust http://code.google.com/p/thrust/ to get a first version working.

Regarding FpGrowth, is there anything that can be done in parallel? Building dynamic trees and tree traversal are generally not considered to be easily implemented in CUDA efficiently.

Comment: "In CUDA there are no pointers, no strings, no printing"? That is misleading at best. There are certainly pointers in CUDA. You can easily use char* strings, too. You can even use print using printf in recent versions, though you probably shouldn't if you want good performance.